# navbar right buckling at screen size over 1900 pixels

Tags: html, css

I have **[THIS](http://codeandcode.co/navbar/main.html)** navbar on my site. i have custom coded the HTMl and the CSS , nothing overly fancy , HTML below:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">

        <button class="menu-btn"id="menu-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>

        <ul class="nav-left">
            <li><a href="">ABOUT lalalala</a></li>
            <li><a href="">WHY a second citizenship?</a></li>
            <li><a href="">tools</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">
            <img src="img/logo/fairbridge-logo.png" alt="fairbridge logo">
        </a>

        <ul class="nav-right">
            <li><a href="">Advantages</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lalalala code of ethics</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>      


    </div>

    <ul class="nav-mini">

        <li><a href="">ABOUT lalalalala</a></li>
        <li><a href="">WHY a second citizenship?</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Advantages</a></li>
        <li><a href="">lalalalala code of ethics</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>  

</nav>
```

CSS below:

I have the following code for the navbar:

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .nav-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar .nav-mini {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar [class*="nav-"] > li a:after {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        content: '';
        left: 20%;
        right: 20%;
        bottom: -10px;
        background: #1b1464;
        height: 2px;
    }

    .navbar [class*="nav-"] > li a:hover:after {
        -webkit-animation-name: nav-line;
        -o-animation-name: nav-line;
        animation-name: nav-line;
        -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
        -o-animation-duration: .3s;
        animation-duration: .3s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .nav-right {
        float: right;
    }
    .navbar [class*="nav-"] {
        padding: 3.93em 0;
    }
    .navbar [class*="nav-"] li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 2.14em;
    }
    .navbar .nav-left li:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .navbar .nav-left li:last-child {
        margin-right: 2.14em;
    }

    .menu-btn {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Now when i view this menu on a screen of 1900+ then the nav on the right side will buckle and come down , why is that happening ??

Comment: It also happens if the screen is smaller than 1200 and also when you zoom out quite far.

Comment: @GolezTrol absolutly , thanks :D , but for smaller screens i have a remedy ! :)